# Ground state of hydrogen atom, $e^{-\kappa r }$ or $e^{-\kappa r }/ r$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, atomic-physics, schroedinger-equation, ground-state

The ground state must be an $s$-wave state, so it depends only on the radius $r$. I cannot remember the exact form, but I know it must be one of the two.

Is there any simple way to determine which one is the right one? I do not want to apply the $\nabla^2$ directly to the wave function, as I do not remember the form of the $\nabla^2$ even for an $s$-state.

I tried to use the normalization condition, but the $1/r$ singularity is normalizable in three dimensions.

Comment: https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/University_of_California_Davis/UCD_Chem_107B%3A_Physical_Chemistry_for_Life_Scientists/Chapters/4%3A_Quantum_Theory/4.10%3A_The_Schr%C3%B6dinger_Wave_Equation_for_the_Hydrogen_Atom

Comment: Easy to remember: $\Delta \frac{f(r)}{r}=\frac{f^{\prime \prime}(r)}{r}-4 \pi \delta^{(3)}(\vec{x}) f(0)$.

Comment: @Pierre The OP appears to be looking for a mnemonic/shortcut, not the actual well-known answer...

Comment: @Cosmaz Zachos Ah, ok, I see.